# Implementing RxSwift with TRON

Tags: rx-swift

I am trying to start using RxSwift, therefore I tried to create a function that does a request and I tried to implement the rxResult() function that comes with [TRON](https://github.com/MLSDev/TRON), the HTTP library I use. But the documentation on this is not very detailed. Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I am doing wrong? This is the function I have written:

```
static func readAllWithRx() {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Constants.kTokenUserDefaultsKey) as! String
    let url = URL(string: "api/url")!
    let request: APIRequest<AssessmentResponse, MyAppError> = APIHelper.tron.request(url.absoluteString)

    _ = request.rxResult().subscribe(onNext: { AssessmentResponse in
        print("RX AssessmentResponse \(AssessmentResponse)")
    }, onError: { Error in

    }, onCompleted: { 

    }, onDisposed: { 

    })
}
```

Finally I try to call this request within my Controller using:

```
let read = Assessments.readAllWithRx()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’re 2 things at the beginning:

1. `let read = Assessments.readAllWithRx()` assumes the function returns something synchronously
2. Implementation of readAllWithRx you posted doesn’t return anything.

I’ve never used TRON, but as far as I can see, its `rxResult()` returns an `Observable<T>` where `T` is a type of the response. In this case, to get `asynchronously` AssesmentResponse, you need to subscribe to the observable (as you already did by the way).

Here's an example - an updated implementation of your readAllWithRx (won’t compiled probably, writing code in notepad):

```
static func readAllWithRx() -> Observable<AssessmentResponse> {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Constants.kTokenUserDefaultsKey) as! String
    let url = URL(string: "api/url")!    
    let request: APIRequest<AssessmentResponse, MyAppError> = APIHelper.tron.request(url.absoluteString)
    return request.rxResult()
}
```

then, if you need to get AssessmentResponse somewhere in the code:

```
Assessments.readAllWithRx().subscribe(onNext: { result in
    // your response here
    print(result)
})
```